# OneHotEncoder Showing error while encoding two columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, data-science-model, one-hot-encoding

I am encoding two columns with index numbers 1 and 2 that is column number 2 and 3, using the following code, however, I am facing an error of invalid syntax : If I am using only 1 in the index value it is ok, please help on this.. how can I encode two columns simultaneously using OneHotEncoder here.

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('encoder', OneHotEncoder(),[1:2])], remainder ='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
```

If I am using the following it is ok but I want to encode the other column as well.

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('encoder', OneHotEncoder(),[1])], remainder ='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('encoder', OneHotEncoder(),[1,2])], remainder ='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
```

Note that you are passing [1:2] as the list of indices to apply the transformation on the `ColumnTransformer` but it should be [1,2]

Comment: : please note that I have changed that and I am facing the following errors now :
Input contains NaN However, I have checked my data there is no NaN value. Do you have any input on this. Thanks.

Comment: The complete error is ```ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')```so In your place I would check if I have an inf value somewhere

Comment: @ Julio Jesus : I have checked the dtype it is int64 , so there is no nan or inf value. While running the code it is showing 
For a sparse output, all columns should be a numeric or convertible to a numeric.